# C++11 STL container array without a name

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

So i have this homework to do and i'm trying to process an array of integers... and ive been given some code written by my instruction and i am very confused on how i can process an array without the name being passed... here ill show you what i mean.

Ive been given this class and i need to write some of the member functions.

```
class TurtleGraphics
{
private:
const static size_t NROWS = 22;  // number of rows in floor
const static size_t NCOLS = 70;  // number of colums in floor

const static int STARTING_ROW = 0;    // row that turtle will start in
const static int STARTING_COL = 0;    // column that turtle will start in

const static int STARTING_DIRECTION = 6; // direction that turtle 
                      // will be facing at the start
                      // 6 as in 6 o'clock on an analog clock
                      // The other 3 possible values are 3,9 and 12 o'clock

const static bool STARTING_PEN_POSITION = false; // Pen will be up when 
                            // program starts
                            // false means pen up, true means pen down

void displayFloor() const;  // will display floor on the screen

std::array <std::array <bool, NCOLS>, NROWS> m_Floor;

public:
const static int ARRAY_SIZE = 250;

TurtleGraphics(void); //ctor will init. floor to all "false" values, 
                      //     as well as initialization of other data members
void processTurtleMoves( const std::array< int, ARRAY_SIZE> );  // will process
                   // the commands contained in array "commands"    
};
```

Im trying to write the void processTurtleMoves(const std::array< int, ARRAY_SIZE> );

can anyone tell me why the array has no name, or why it doesn't need a name, or if this is just a mistake ?

The main issue is that im trying to process this array without a name and i'm very confused.

PS. don't have time to get in contact with instructor.

Comment: array ought to be passed const ref or by value.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should probably pass the array by reference.

Answer (score 4):

In the function *definition*, you give the function parameter a name:

```
void TurtleGraphics::processTurtleMoves(const std::array<int, ARRAY_SIZE> commands)
//                                                                        ^^^^^^^^
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To expand a bit on @Kerrek's answer: A function declaration (where there is no function body) can either have a name for a paramter, or not, it doesn't matter (the compiler actually ignores it). The definition must have the name - and if the names don't match between the declaration and the definition, it won't be an error. Although, IMO, it's best to give the argument a name (might be easier for a user of the function), and it's best to keep the name the same between the declaration and the definition.

Comment: @Steve: The definition doesn't need parameter names either. It only does if you want to refer to the parameters.